# Зачем удалять динамические массивы, и что будет если их не удалять?

Tags: c++, указатели, память, динамические-массивы, выделение-памяти

нам в универе сказали, что мы обязаны постоянно удалять массивы, если они  динамические, но я так и не понял зачем и почему.
Вот, например, код на С++ с динамическим выделением памяти для массива `arr`:

```
void main(){
      int size = 10;
      int *arr = new int[size];
}
```

Почему я должен его удалять, какие ошибки в дальнейшем будут, если я буду постоянно использовать вот этот `arr`?

Comment: В данном примере — никаких ошибок не будет, используйте на здоровье

Comment: Только вот если внутри массивов будут сложные объекты с деструкторами или если массивы используются временно, то отсутствие удаления приведёт к утечкам памяти и глюкам из-за неосвобождённых ресурсов системы

Comment: @andreymal, Ну в этом не будет ошибок, ибо я сам проверил и ничего не было, но вот допустим есть какой-то большой проект, где нужно, допустим, очень много динамических массивов, то вот что может произойти не так, из-за чего программа будет некорректно работать?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Представьте себе городскую систему проката автомобилей. Не очень большую. Вы постоянно берете автомобили напрокат, пользуетесь и не сдаете, но и сами больше не ездите. Постепенно все автомобили будут исчерпаны, ездить будет не на чем. Это аналог просто не удаления (освобождения) памяти.

Вы попользовались, выбросили ключи и все бумаги и даже не знаете, где теперь этот автомобиль. Это - потерянная память (утечка). Вы бы и рады ее вернуть, чтоб было на чем проехать - но не можете этого сделать. Это - если вы затерли (переписали, кончилось время жизни) все указатели на выделенную память. (Правда, в системах со сборкой мусора время от времени - обычно, когда машины заканчиваются - специальная служба занимается тем, что объезжает город в поисках заброшенных автомобилей и возвращает их в прокат.)

Вы вернули автомобиль, но сделали себе копию ключа. Если вы попробуете им воспользоваться - это уже будет кража, и приедет полиция. А может, и не приедет, если никто не заметит... Undefined behaviour! :) Это - попытка получить доступ по указателю на освобожденную память.

Вы сделали красивые копии документов и, пользуясь тем, что при возврате автомобиля возвращают залог, хотите сдать его еще раз. Это - попытка повторного освобождения памяти. Опять же - это воровство, и приедет полиция. Скорее всего. А может, и прокатит... Undefined behaviour, что вы хотите...

Вы пытаетесь сдать в прокат собственный автомобиль (ну, может, залог в прокате такой большой? :)) Это - попытка освобождения памяти, не выделенной менеджером памяти, например, попытка освободить память, выделенную под переменную в стеке. И опять же - это воровство со всеми вытекающими последствиями...

Примерно так...

P.S. Да, автомобили бывают и особо интеллектуальные, которые сами берут в той же системе напрокат, например, колеса или там прицепы, и пока вы не сдадите такой автомобиль - колеса тоже будут не сданы. Это к конструкторам/деструкторам динамически выделяемых объектов.

P.P.S. Когда вы уезжаете из города, он разрушается вместе с прокатом, так что сдали вы автомобили или не сдали - уже не имеет значения... Это к тому, что по завершению программы не так уж важно, оставалась ли не освобожденная память. Но, если у вас выработается из-за этого плохая привычка не сдавать машины вовремя, в новом городе у вас могут быть проблемы...

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при создании большого количества динамических массивов, я буду тупо много жрать оперативки в никуда, без их дальнейшего удаления? А если и захочу потом в дальнейшем использовать, то уже не смогу?

Comment: То, что для вас выделено, и не удалено (и указатель вами сохранен) - используйте, когда хотите.

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо

Comment: Красивая аналогия, Harry :)

Comment: @WartVader, вы можете отметить ответ как «принятый», нажав галочку рядом с ним.