# Не очищается память массива

Tags: c++, память, выделение-памяти

```
int* a[6];
a[0] = new int;
delete[]a;
```

Почему выскакивает исключение? "*Test_proj.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова*"

Comment: элементы массива  живут на стеке, один из элементов хранит адрес объекта, живущим в куче. Что  вы пытаетесь очищать?...

Comment: мне надо очистить полностью массив "a"

Comment: вы его не очистите, потому что его элементы не созданы  вами с помощью new, они лежат рядом, на стеке, и  уничтожатся  на выходе из функции, без ваших указаний.. Вы можете и должны лишь освободить память, куда указывает первый элемент массива:  ` delete  a[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом деле, почему?

Давайте посмотрим вместе.

```
int* a[6];
```

В стеке (не в динамической памяти! менеджер памяти тут ни при чем, память освободится автоматически при выходе `a` из области видимости) выделено место под массив из 6 указателей.

```
a[0] = new int;
```

В первый элемент массива записывается адрес *одной* переменной типа `int`, для которой выделено место в динамической памяти.

```
delete[]a;
```

Вы пытаетесь освободить память для всего массива - к которому, как уже было сказано, менеджер памяти отношения не имеет, так как массив находится в совсем другой памяти. Т.е. в рамках [данной модели](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012395/195342) вы пытаетесь сдать в прокат собственный автомобиль, который вы в прокате не брали :)

И еще - что вы понимаете под "*очистить массив*" (в названии вопроса)? Может, вы хотите вообще не освободить память, а, например, обнулить его значения? Уточните этот момент.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет:

```
int* a;
a = new int(6);
delete[]a;
```