# При передаче динамического массива из функции нету утечки памяти?

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

У меня есть функция:

```
int** matrix(){
    int** arr_func = new int* [3];
    //...
    return are_func

}
```

Основная часть программы:

```
int main() {


    int** infoBusy = new int* [1];

    infoBusy = matrix();
    //....
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    delete[] infoBusy[i];
}

delete[] infoBusy;
```

Матрица `infoBusy` удаляется в основном коде, но удаляется ли матрица `arr_func` что в функции?

Comment: Массив выделенный внутри `matrix()` вы удаляете в `main()` (здесь: `delete[] infoBusy;`). А указатель на первый элемент массива, выделенного в начале `main()` безвозвратно теряется.

Comment: @wololo это как-то можно исправить?

Comment: Не выделять массив в начале `main`: `new int* [1];`? Зачем он вам, если вы его никак не используете? Судя по приведённому фрагменту кода, функция `matrix()` самостоятельно занимается распределением памяти.

Comment: Массив из одного элемента не удаляется, массив из 3 элементов удаляется, но для его содержимого удалится только первый элемент, остальные два останутся. Лучше не делайте так, используйте std::vector<std::vector<int>> или лучше одномерный массив с индексацией вида j*n + i

Comment: Вообще любопытно. Далеко не в первый раз вижу здесь вопрос про утечку памяти, где указатель на выделенную память тут же перезаписывается: `T* var = new ...; var = foo();`. Эта ваша идея так написать или где-то вычитали?

Comment: @wololo идея моя. Мне нужно что бы было два массива один в мэйне второй в функции(метод класса на самом деле). Я сначало создавал динамический массив в main и в функции я получал указатель на массив. Но преподавателю не понравилось и он сказал переделать так, как я написал изначально в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утечка есть, но не там, где вы ее ждете.

То, что выделено в функции, честно удаляется. Утечка при перезаписи -

```
int** infoBusy = new int* [1];  // Вот этот указатель не сохраняется и "утекает"
infoBusy = matrix();
```

Пишите просто

```
int** infoBusy = matrix();
```

Смотрите - утечка возникает, когда выделена динамическая память, но не удалена. Как в вашем исходном коде - память выделена, указатель записан в переменную, тут же перезаписан - и теперь при всем желании его невозможно получить, чтобы освободить выделенную память. Утечка!

В функции она у вас выделена, указатель на нее возвращен, и память по этому указателю удалена. Сама *переменная* `are_func` располагается в стеке и ее память освобождается при завершении функции. Еще раз - память, выделенная для переменной, а не выделенная память, указатель на которую хранится в этой переменной.

Почитайте эту [модель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012395/195342). В ее рамках возврат из функции - вы просто передаете документы и ключи от прокатной машины другу. Если друг, попользовавшись, честно сдаст ее обратно - никаких проблем не возникнет...