# Почему при освобождении памяти, можно присваивать значения уже освобожденной части памяти через другой указатель?

Tags: c++

Почему при освобождении памяти, можно присваивать значения уже освобожденной части памяти для программы через другой указатель?

```
int* ptr = new int(5);

int* ptr_ = ptr;

delete ptr;

*ptr_ = 1;

std::cout << *ptr_;
```

Comment: [Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer)

Comment: Неопределенное поведение - оно такое неопределенное....

Понимаете, вы можете перебегать дорогу на красный свет светофора. Можете переходить ее с завязанными глазами и заткнутыми ушами. И у вас это будет отлично получаться... до поры до времени.

И то, что после нескольких переходов вы остались живы и здоровы - является ли основанием говорить, что "на красный переходить можно, я проверял!"?

Comment: У @Harry есть очень красивый ответ на эту тему - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012395/228791 Почему он его сам не привел, не знаю, но он должен ответить и на заданный вами вопрос и на еще не заданные :)

Comment: @Mikhailo Честно говоря, я о нем и не вспомнил...

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле глупый вопрос.

Представьте себе, что вы арендуете комнату в какой-нибудь общаге. У вас есть ключ от этой комнаты и вы в любое время вольны *законно* в неё входить. Но вот вы решили отказаться от аренды и комнату освободили. Однако у вас остался от неё ключ. Ну либо вы сдали ключ, но остался сделанный ранее дубликат. А значит вы по-прежнему можете в эту комнату входить, однако это уже будет *незаконно*! И если вы будете так поступать, то с вами потенциально могут случиться разные неприятности: вас может забрать полиция, или новый законный арендатор комнаты может выкинуть вас в окно.

Так и с памятью/указателями. Если вы зарезервировали область память с помощью оператора `new`, то вы можете присваивать туда значения *законно*. Если вы освободили эту область, то вы по-прежнему можете присваивать туда значения, ведь у вас остался "ключ", т.е. указатель на эту область. Но это уже будет *незаконно*. И если вы будете так поступать, то с вашей программой потенциально могут случиться разные неприятности, которые совокупно обозначаются одним понятием: *Undefined Behavior (неопределённое поведение)*.

Так что правильный ответ на ваш вопрос: *нельзя* присваивать значения уже освобожденной части памяти через *любой* указатель.

Comment: А почему вопрос глупый-то?

Comment: @eanmos Потому что как бы очевидно, что если выделенная область памяти освобождается, то физически она никуда не девается. И если вы запишите туда значение, то оно туда запишется, а потом вы можете его оттуда прочитать. Другое дело, что *менеджер памяти* будет считать эту область свободной и распоряжаться ей на своё усмотрение. Например, отдать эту же область (или её часть) по запросу другого оператора new (вызванного из другого потока, библиотеки или другой части вашей же программы позже). Так что если уж освободили "комнату", то будьте добры "съехать")))

Comment: @eanmos и кстати, ситуация, когда некоторая часть памяти после освобождения перестанет существовать, вполне себе возможна. Например, при нехватке *физической* памяти на вашем ПК часть страниц свободной *виртуальной* памяти программы может быть уничтожена (decommited) операционной системой. В этом случае попытка туда присвоить значение приведёт к падению программы. В этом и есть суть неопределённого поведения - может произойти всё, что угодно, и всё что угодно может не произойти.

Answer (score 2):

Это одинаково нельзя делать через `ptr` и через `ptr_`.

Это в любом случае неопределенное поведение - результат может быть любой, в том числе отсутствие ошибки.

Чтобы ловить такие ошибки во время разработки, используйте Address Sanitizer (как его включить - зависит от компилятора).